# dynamoDB ExclusiveStartKey not assigning

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to pass a value to `ExclusiveStartKey` in the `dynamoDB`. However, that value is not assigning to `ExclusiveStartKey`.
Can someone help me here please to identify why the key is not assigning when its pass through an argument value and why its working when assign manually?
Thanks.

```
class VolumesParallel(object):
    def strike(self, *item):
        Eva_Key = item[0]  # Type is string
        # Eva_Key= 'cfa9be92-f422-40fe-91b6'   if key is assigned manually like this its working
        print(Eva_Key)   # Assigned key is printing successfully 
        dyndb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
        tbl = dyndb.Table('delete')
        reqst = tbl.scan(
            ExclusiveStartKey={
                    'findingId': Eva_Key
                },
            Limit=1,
            )
        data = reqst['Items']
        print (data)  # this output is null -> []
```

Comment: The problem is probably that you use `item[0]` as `Eva_Key` and pass in `item` as the exclusive start key. Without more context it's difficult to say if that's correct or not.

Comment: sorry it was a typo error when i transfer the code here. I have corrected it. If can please check again.